# Autorelease: Must [ retain] on member variables?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, retain, autorelease

Say I have a `BasicEngine` class:

```
@interface BasicEngine : GfxEngine{

    NSMutableDictionary *keyNodes;
    AbstractVirtualJoystick *input0;
}
```

The related implementation goes as follows:

```
@implementation BasicEngine
- (id)init {

    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {

        keyNodes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    return self;
}
```

My understanding is that calling `[ dictionary]` returns an autoreleased object. However, this dictionary should be kept in memory as long as the `BasicEngine` instance is available.

I realise I'm missing something as `keyNodes` quickly becomes a `nil` object.
Using `[keyNodes retain]` in the `init` method just helps, but I can't understand why a class member needs to be retained.

Please help me understand this :-)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`retain` implies ownership of the retainer on the retainee. Since `keyNodes` is a class member, your engine "owns" it, and thus should `retain` on it.

Under the hood `retain` is incrementing the reference count on `keyNodes`, which signals to the system that one more object is interested in keeping whatever `keyNodes` points to around in memory. Similarly, you're expected to call `release` on `keyNodes` in your `dealloc` method, which will decrement the retain count as your engine no longer "owns" `keyNodes`.

Comment: Ah thanks for this clear and concise explanation, definitely adding this to my cheat sheet ;-) Thanks Kevboh!

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any more questions, I'd be happy to answer them. Apple has some good docs on memory management [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html), as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to maintain `keyNodes` object until `BasicEngine` is available, you can also implement with singleton pattern to make them static.

see also : http://xperienced.com.pl/blog/3-ways-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-objective-c